# Linking AppCenter installationId to the back-end user - is that secure?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

As per my understanding, to use push notification i need to pass AppCenter.GetInstallIdAsync() (installationid) to my back-end server and link the installation Id to the user using my Rest API.

I am wondering, is it secure enough to allow link any applicationid (which is a simple Guid) to the user ? What is someone will pass to the rest API a GUID that he will guess?

Is there some best practices for that?

Comment: I can't for certain vouch for the security of the process, But if it feel's like a concern for you, Why not encrypt the ID? You mention your using a Rest API maybe using something as simple as a hash Encryption on the server side and you'll know the decryption sequence so that wont be floating along, Then if by chance someone doe's intercept  a response it'll me no more then gibberish to them?, as for your question, I can't see what harm those ID's can do if your using Customer/Secret Key's

Comment: @Azurry Encrypt the Installationid in the App itself is not safe because everyone will be able to decompile and see the logic. I don't see a way to make my back-end from manipulating installation id.